# The term 'test' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. YML-file

Tags: maven, continuous-integration, yaml, gitlab-ci

I'm trying to make a yml-file for gitlab-ci/cd, because the template for maven didn't work so I tried a tutorial online (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jav4vbUrqII). The building-part of the yml works, but the testing-part doesn't work because it isn't recognized as a command. I think the pipeline is using powershell (I'm on windows).

Extra context:
The first time I followed the tutorial I got 2 other problems before this one.
The first one was that `stages config should be a string of arrays` so I changed it to arrays of strings.

The second one was that `'touch' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program`, so what I did was changing `touch` to `new-item`, because it was a replacement I found online.

But now I can't seem to find a replacement for `test`.

yml-file:

```
stages: ["build", "test"]
build:
    stage: build
    script:
        - echo "Building..."
        - mkdir build
        - new-item build/info.txt
    artifacts:
        paths:
        - build/

test:
    stage: test
    script:
        - echo "Testing..."
        - test -f "build/info.txt"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Windows equivalent in Powershell is

```
Test-Path "build/info.txt" -PathType leaf
```

Comment: Thank you! I've been struggling to find the equivalent the whole weekend :'D